# Supremum vs. Maximum in the definition of the Lp norm

Tags: normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

The $L_p$ norm $||A||_p$ is defined as

$$\sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||_p}{||x||_p} = \max_{||x||_p = 1} ||Ax||_p \tag{1}$$

I'm not quite getting why the LHS uses $\sup$ but the RHS uses $\max$. I know how both are defined but somehow I don't get it. The maximum requires the solution to be contained in the candidate set while the supremum does not. Thus, why does (1) hold?

Answer (score 2):

In finite dimensional space (which is the case here) the unit sphere $\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid ||x||_p=1\}$ is compact then the supremum of the continuous function $x\mapsto ||Ax||_p$ is attained.

Comment: When we are dealing with matrices we are always dealing with a finite dimensional space right? Or how did you infer that we are dealing with a finite dimensional space? Do you know a reason for why they don't define it via the max right away and use sup?

Comment: Yes matrices are always defined over a finite dimensional space. The definition given holds in general, that is over both infinite dimensional spaces (operators) and finite dimensional spaces (matrices). That is why it isn't defined via the max right away. The finite-dimensional property is what allows it to be specified as max instead of sup.